# LightSwitch Build Error: The target "CreateManifestResourceNames" does not exist in the project

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have been banging my head against the wall about this problem with a LightSwitch project. It runs just fine inside VS 2013, but on all but one of our developers' PCs the automated build with msbuild fails. We have also been unable to run these builds on our build server, because we keep getting this error. We carefully compared the setup of the one PC that can build with the others, but all differences we found and eliminated did not make a bit of difference.

Here is the command we issue to start the build (obviously, these build commands are all encapsulated in build scripts, but this is what it amounts to):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Release /v:quiet /t:Publish /property:PublishLocation=C:\Build\dispatcher\2.3.1007\server\software\Administration\DISP.Administration\Publish C:\Build\dispatcher\2.3.1007\server\software\Administration\DISP.Administration\Administration.sln
```

And as a result we get:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.40629.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2317,7): error MSB4057: The target "
CreateManifestResourceNames" does not exist in the project. [C:\Build\dispatcher\2.3.1007\server\software\Administra
tion\DISP.Administration\AdministrationTool.lsxtproj]
```

By the way, I am getting the same error when using the project file AdministrationTool.lsxtproj as the last argument of the build command.

I'll be happy to provide more info if someone will let me know what additional info is needed.

Comment: For anyone getting this error with a dotnet core project: do a "dotnet restore" first